# Trouble passing mpsc sync channel in warp handler

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, rust, warp

I'm new to rust and encountered an issue while building an API with warp. I'm trying to pass some requests to another thread with a channel(trying to avoid using arc/mutex). Still, I noticed that when I pass an mpsc::sync::Sender to a warp handler, I get this error.

"std::sync::mpsc::Sender cannot be shared between threads safely"

and

"the trait `Sync` is not implemented for `std::sync::mpsc::Sender"

Can someone lead me in the right direction?

```
use std::sync::mpsc::Sender;

pub async fn init_server(run_tx: Sender<Packet>) {
    let store = Store::new();
    let store_filter = warp::any().map(move || store.clone());

    let run_tx_filter = warp::any().map(move || run_tx.clone());
    let update_item = warp::get()
        .and(warp::path("v1"))
        .and(warp::path("auth"))
        .and(warp::path::end())
        .and(post_json())
        .and(store_filter.clone())

        .and(run_tx_filter.clone()) //where I'm trying to send "Sender"
        .and_then(request_token);


    let routes = update_item;

    println!("HTTP server started on port 8080");
    warp::serve(routes).run(([127, 0, 0, 1], 3030)).await;
}
```

```
pub async fn request_token(
    req: TokenRequest,
    store: Store,
    run_tx: Sender<Packet>,
) -> Result<impl warp::Reply, warp::Rejection> {
    let (tmp_tx, tmp_rx) = std::sync::mpsc::channel();

    run_tx
        .send(Packet::IsPlayerLoggedIn(req.address, tmp_tx))
        .unwrap();

    let logged_in = tmp_rx.recv().unwrap();

    if logged_in {
        return Ok(warp::reply::with_status(
            "Already logged in",
            http::StatusCode::BAD_REQUEST,
        ));
    }
    Ok(warp::reply::with_status("some token", http::StatusCode::OK))
}
```

I've looked through some of the examples for warp, and was also wondering what are some good resources to get knowledgable of the crate. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you're using `std::sync::mpsc::Sender`. [std::sync](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/mpsc/struct.Sender.html#impl-Sync-for-Sender%3CT%3E) implements `!Sync`, so you won't be able to use that. You don't want to use that anyway since it's blocking.

When you use `async` functionality in rust, you need to provide a runtime for it. The good news is that warp runs on the `tokio` runtime, so you should have access to [tokio::sync::mpsc](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/sync/mpsc/struct.Sender.html#impl-Sync-for-Sender%3CT%3E) If you take a look at that link, the Sender for that mpsc implementation implements `Sync` and `Send` so it's safe to share across threads.

TLDR:

Use `tokio::sync::mpsc` instead of `std::sync::mpsc` and this won't be an issue.